# Representing Java Object in OWL

Tags: java, owl, ontology, protege

I have two `classes` one `Student` having *name* as an attribute and another `College` also having *name* as an attribute. I want to represent same information (without creating different Data Properties for 'name') in OWL. As both classes are disjoint `Student Disjoint College`. So `name Domain Student` and `name Domain College` considers both *Student* and *College* as same.

Here the question is if I am having some attribute (java object attribute) which are broadly used in many more classes then how to model this in OWL ? Also how to get the same information back from OWL ? (Represent JAVA in OWL and then get information from OWL convert it into JAVA required in one case for my project)

Comment: What is the question then?

Comment: For defining the domain of a property you can used arbitrary complex OWL class expression, thus, in your example you could say `name Domain (Student or College)`

Comment: And there's no need to define a domain for name at all, really, if it's going to be so broadly applied (and "name" does seem like a pretty broadly applicable property).

Comment: If i didnt give domain to "name" they its domain will be "Thing". and if there are many more classes containing "name" as an attribute then I am ending giving all of them in Domain with "or" operator.